# read only filtered records from Excel using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I need to know if it's possible to read only the filtered records from an excel file using SSIS. My current testing indicates that all records are read and filters are completely ignored.

It's seems like this should have been asked before, but I just can't find the answer.

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a macro to copy the required rows to another sheet and then read from there? Reading only the filtered part is going to be tough IMO except for a script component maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of writing your own source in .NET to use the Office libraries, I am not aware of a way for the native SSIS Excel data source to know about the filter.

If you have the opportunity to pre-process the file, a trick we often used was to manually open the file up, add an additional column, ImportThis, and fill with a 'Y' value. It's not the most graceful way of handling it but it was the most cost effective.

Comment: Looks like you are the winner.  Custom Script source, here I come.